# Will my ranking drop if I don't comply with GDPR?

Tags: google, gdpr

I have a site that is not doing well on search and I don't know why. My site doesn't have the GDPR popup, will that be an issue with Google rankings? If so, how does Google know?

Comment: I don't believe that Google are looking for GDPR compliance per-se, but (at least according to my SEO expert and his group) care that you have a privacy policy.

Comment: I'd like to use this opportunity to point out that forcing the user to click on an OK button on a cookie banner has nothing to do with GDPR compliance. According to the GDPR, you either have a good, legitimate reason for processing the user's data (in which case no consent is required), or you don't (in which case a *freely given* and *informed* consent is required - which is a criterion that many banners don't satisfy and which Google cannot "check" automatically).

Answer (score 2):

To my knowledge, Google has never announced that GDPR compliance is a factor in their ranking algorithm, so it's reasonably safe to assume that your ranking issues stem from a different cause.

However, GDPR compliance can come into play if you integrate Google products into your website, [for example AdSense](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/9035987?hl=en).

For a general overview of ways to increase ranking, see:
[What are the best ways to improve a site's position in Google?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2/what-are-the-best-ways-to-improve-a-sites-position-in-google)